# How do I get Firebase to add new users and not overwrite current users (iOS, Xcode 8)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xcode8

This code keeps overwriting the database after a new user is created. This is the code that I have put in:

```
func handleRegister() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text
        else {
            print("Form is not Valid")
            return
        }

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user: User?, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(Error.self)
            return
        }

        guard (user?.uid) != nil else { return }
    })

    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "//Firebase link")
    let usersReference = ref.child("Users").child("uid")
    let values = ["name": name, "email": email]

    usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err.self)
            return
        }
        print("Successfully saved user in Firebase DB")
    })
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something really simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: let usersReference = ref.child("Users").child("uid") providing aid Statically ? you need to pass the current aid or you can opt for unique key everytime so data don't get replaced

Comment: How would I do that? I tried everyone's suggestions in the post and the only thing that is working is the method that keeps replacing the data.

Comment: check my edited answer it will clear step by step

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
after your

```
guard (user?.uid) != nil else {
  return
}
```

put your remaining code below it:

```
let ref = Database.database()... //your code
//put inside the completion block of create user
//the rest of your code up to the updateChildValues
```

and use this uid as the parameter for your child in **users**

so it would become:

```
let usersReference = ref.child("Users").child(uid)
```

note that the **uid** is not enclosed with double quotes

you have to put it inside the createUser **completion block** because the scope of your **user?.uid** is only up to that block.

Comment: I changed the code to what you put above and for some weird reason Xcode wants to change the guard let line back to the one I had previously. After I do that, when I take the double quotes off .child(uid) Xcode throws an error saying 'use of unresolved identifier'. I have imported all the Firebase modules into the project if that helps.

Comment: ohh, my bad. the scope of the guard let is only up to the **completion block** of your create user. try moving your block of code from the "ref" variable up to the updateChildValues inside the create user completion block

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if you find it confusing.

Comment: Okay, I will give it a shot. I have a few other things to do today, so I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

use below code as in your code everytime you run handler data is replaced as you are providing static "uid" use below code to add a node with current user uid which is assigned to user at time of account creation in firebase DB

```
//before viewDidLoad declare a global databaseRef as

let  databaseRef = Database.Database().reference //this will be used as base reference In all handlers 
var name : String = ""
var Uid : String = ""
var email : String = ""
var nameString : String = ""

func createUser(){
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.EmailTextField.text!, password: self.PasswordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

        if error == nil {
            print("You have successfully signed up")
            //Goes to the Setup page which lets the user take a photo for their profile picture and also chose a username

            self.nameString = self.nameTextField.text!

            self.AddUserDetails()

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })

        } else {
                 //this block shows error if exist
                 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            //this is my activity indicator
            self.spinnerView.isHidden = true
            self.spinner.isHidden = true
            self.spinner.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}

func AddUserDetails(){
    //I make use of user nsobject class to get all details
    //you can also make use of some global strings
    self.name = self.nameString //name string store current display name
    //name string contains name which I am taking as input when a user want to sign up as a textField text
    self.email = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)! //current email
    self.Uid = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)! //current uid


    let user:[String : AnyObject] = ["email": self.email as AnyObject,"name":self.name as AnyObject,"uID":self.Uid as AnyObject]

    databaseRef.child("users").child(self.Uid).setValue(user)

}
```

Comment: This one helps, but when I put the code in, I have 8 errors. The top half of the code works from "func createUser()" down to "self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)" Beyond that, I have errors all the way down to the "databaseRef.child" I can't figure out what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Please have a look at my edited answer and tell me if still some errors exist if still they do , tell me which line gives you error

Comment: I wil try it out and let you know what happens. It might not be till later on today. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes sure Tell me if issue exist I will try to sort it out .

Answer (score -1):

you are not calling your code to write in database inside the callback of user creation. So its creating user reference with old uid and hence overwrite the values.

```
 Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user: User?, error) in

        if error != nil {
        print(Error.self)

        return
    }
// after this you are sure user created and now move your calls here 
//to write in firebase database.
    guard (user?.uid) != nil else {
        return
    }
})
```